# multiple mysql statements in one transaction c#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

In this code I insert into 2 tables `tbl_inv` and `tbl_line`. First I insert records into `tbl_inv`(invoice) and then I insert into `tbl_line`(invoice lines).  When a record is inserted to `tbl_inv`, `invno` is auto generated (auto increment column) and then that `invno` should be inserted in `tbl_line` table (for all matching records).
The following code inserts only into table `tbl_inv` and not to `tbl_line`.
Any help?

```
const string InsertStatement1 = @"
    INSERT INTO tbl_inv (cname, date, duedate,subtotal,vat,total) 
    VALUES(@cname, @date, @duedate,@subtotal,@vat,@total )
    ";
            const string InsertStatement2 = @"
    INSERT INTO tbl_line (invno,pname,qty,unitprice,amount) 
    VALUES(@invno,@pname,@qty,@unitprice,@amount )
    ";

            cn.Open();
            using (MySqlTransaction sqlTrans =cn.BeginTransaction())
            using (MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(InsertStatement1, cn, sqlTrans))
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@cname", comboBox1.Text);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@date", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@duedate", dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@subtotal", textBox6.Text);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@vat", textBox7.Text);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@total", textBox9.Text);


                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                var last = "select LAST_INSERT_ID()";

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in mg2.Rows)
                {

                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@invno",last );
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pname", row.Cells[1].Value);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", row.Cells[2].Value);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unitprice", row.Cells[3].Value);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", row.Cells[4].Value);

                    sqlCommand.CommandText = InsertStatement2;
                }
                sqlTrans.Commit();
            }
```

Comment: get the result of last_insert_id() at the time your are inserting the record in tbl_inv

Comment: Try to do some digging, to learn more about Entity Framework, Linq to SQL and dataset, using those tools you will save more time and you code will be more elegant.

Comment: for example with Entity Framework I can write 3 lines of code to do all of what you are trying to do here and the same thing using linq to sql, for me I'm not fun of dataset because I think it not professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see multiple problems here:

First, you need to execute the `LAST_INSERT_ID` statement using `ExecuteScalar()`, and then use the returned value as the parameter value for the next insert.

Second, you aren't executing the next insert statement(s) at all.

So, it should look something like this:

```
const string InsertStatement1 = @"INSERT INTO tbl_inv (cname, date, duedate, subtotal, vat, total) 
    VALUES (@cname, @date, @duedate, @subtotal, @vat, @total);";
const string InsertStatement2 = @"INSERT INTO tbl_line (invno, pname, qty, unitprice, amount) 
    VALUES (@invno, @pname, @qty, @unitprice, @amount);";

cn.Open();
using (MySqlTransaction sqlTrans = cn.BeginTransaction())
using (MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(InsertStatement1, cn, sqlTrans))
{
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@cname", comboBox1.Text);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@date", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@duedate", dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@subtotal", textBox6.Text);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@vat", textBox7.Text);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@total", textBox9.Text);
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
    sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";
    var o = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    if (o is Int64)
    {
        var id = (Int64)o;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in mg2.Rows)
        {
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invno", id);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pname", row.Cells[1].Value);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", row.Cells[2].Value);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unitprice", row.Cells[3].Value);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", row.Cells[4].Value);
            sqlCommand.CommandText = InsertStatement2;
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    sqlTrans.Commit();
}
```

Comment: I still have the same problem. The record is inserted only into table `tbl_inv` and not to `tbl_line`.

Comment: are you getting any exception? Debug and check once.

Comment: What's the schema for the table `tbl_inv`?  There _is_ an autonumber field, right?

Comment: The code compiles and runs, i don't get any exception. `tbl_inv(invno,cname,date,duedate,subtotal,vat,total) primary key(invno) auto-increment(invno)` and `tbl_line(lineid,invno,pname,qty,unitprice,amount)
primary key(lineid,invno) autoincrement(lineid)`

Comment: Did you step through the code to be sure you get into the `for` loop?  I.e. are there rows in `mg2.Rows` to process, or is it skipping the section entirely for some reason?

Comment: It skips the `if (o is Int64)`. `invno` is of type `bigint`.

Comment: when I comment the `if (o is Int64)` and `var id = (Int64)o` it works! Thank you.

Comment: Ahhhh, yes of course it is.  My mistake.  I've been thinking MS SqlServer a lot lately.